# USB bluetooth dongle cannot recognize previously detected devices

Tags: 16.04, gnome, bluetooth

I got a problem using a bluetooth keyboard with a USB bluetooth dongle between multiple computers. I have Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome 3 on one of my machines and the keyboard is recognized correctly on the first run with the dongle. However, as I plug out the USB dongle to use it on my other machines, and plug it in back, the keyboard is not recognized anymore.

My current workaround is to delete the device, and pair it again from scratch every time I plug in the USB dongle. How can I diagnose and solve this issue?